# Wordpress bloginfo('template_directory') not working in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a custom jquery file in a wordpress site and I am trying to use the bloginfo('template_directory') assigned to a variable to use in the ajax url paths rather than having to type out the full url each time (especially as this is in development on a test site at the moment so need to ensure everything works when moving to the live site on the actual domain), however all that happens is that the php is added to the url, not the directory path.

What I have at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var templateDir = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>";

    // Login
    $('.login-form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        dataString = $(this).serialize() + '&ajax=1';
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: templateDir + "/inc/do-login.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {.
.
.
            }
        });
    });
```

And what I get in the console error is (site url replaced with ...):

```
POST http://www......./...../%3C?php%20get_bloginfo('template_directory')%20?%3E/inc/do-login.php  404 (Not Found)
```

Can anyone shed any light on this please.

Comment: Is this code is in your php page or in JS ??

Comment: It is in JS, and now I realise that it needs to be in my files, not in the js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a Javascript snippet that saves the template dir in a variable, and you can use later using that variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var templateDir = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: So this needs to be outside my jquery?

Comment: @Gautam3164 I guess its not..we can define variable in jQuery like in JS ..so this may not be a case

Comment: @user1260846 Your php script is not rendering..so chk if the above code is in php page or not

Comment: Thank you @Gautam3164 - I have put this snippet above the calls to all the jquery files in the fotter and it is now working. Nice simple solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your `templateDir` variable out of your javascript file. The reason is because your php will not be interpreted. This means your `templateDir` variable will literally be equal to `"<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>";`

Luckily you can can still use javascript variables from other scripts or in your html directly.

Here is one solution.

This is your similar to your script but with a few modifications. Read carefully.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Login
    $('.login-form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        dataString = $(this).serialize() + '&ajax=1';
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: custom.templateDir + "/inc/do-login.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {

            }
        });
    });
```

Now in your `functions.php` you can use use this trick to add javascript variables that can be accessed by your script:

```
function custom_init_js()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_localize_script('jquery', 'custom', array(
        'templateDir' => get_bloginfo('template_url')));
}
add_action('get_header', 'custom_init_js');
```

This will result in the following snippet of javascript being added your html pages.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var custom = {"templateDir":"https://www.website.org/wp-content/themes/yourTheme/"};
/* ]]> */
```

Now you can assess your template directory by using `custom.templateDir` in your script. The custom object comes from the `wp_localize_script` function. You can name this whatever you want.

Additionally you want to use `get_bloginfo('template_url')`, since `template_dir` will get you the file path and not the url, which is what you want.

When using this approach, the `wp_localize_script` is called only when you load the specified script with `wp_enqueue_script`. In this case, I used `jquery`.

`wp_localize_script` is mainly used for internationalization, but can be used to other data.

Here is the codex page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: I have added this to my functions.php and changed the javascript but nothing is being loaded into the page header as indicated??

Comment: Sorry my fault. I made a poor assumption. I thought you were loading jquery using the `enqueue_script` function. I revised my answer to reflect that. The `wp_localize_script` gets loaded when jquery is loaded in this example. But as you found out Gautam3164's solution works also and is simpler.